# Incremental list with tables in RevealJS Quarto

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

I would like to have a slide with incremental lists with a table. Here is some reproducible code:

````
---
title: "Incremental list with tables"
format: revealjs
---

## Slide

::: {.incremental}

- Here some text

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| message: false
library(knitr)
kable(head(iris))
```

- Table above should be incremental with these list points

:::
````

Output:

[image]

The problem is that the table will be always visible and isn't incremental even when using `{.incremental}`. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to create an incremental list of text and tables in revealJS Quarto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fragments](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#fragments) are what you might need.

> Fragments are used to highlight or **incrementally** reveal individual
> elements on a slide.

Also,

> if you have a slide that has more content than can be displayed on a
> single frame there are [two slide-level classes](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/#content-overflow) you can apply to
> mitigate this:

`.smaller` class for a smaller typeface and `.scrollable` class to make off-slide content available by scrolling.

````
---
title: "Incremental list with tables"
format: revealjs
---

## Slide {.scrollable .smaller}

::: {.fragment fragment-index=1}
- Here some text  

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| message: false
library(knitr)
kable(head(iris))
```
:::

::: {.fragment fragment-index=2}
- Table above should be incremental with these list points
:::
````